# Differentiate Restful routes and non-restful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

As far as I know, restful routes are routes that are based on REST architecture. And rails uses restful routes by default. `resource` keyword defines seven restful routes for us. While if I have to define a custom route,

```
resource :photos do
 memeber do
  get 'preview' #non-restful route
 end
end
```

Now `preview` route is defined as non-restful route. Isn't it RESTful route?

**My question is, how can we differentiate RESTful routes and non-RESTful routes? Can u give an example of a custom restful route and non-restful route.**

Comment: It's custom route, not `non-restful`

Comment: so it is a custom `restful` route?

Comment: REST refers to a group of architectural guidelines, not fixed rules. If you consider a `preview` as a resource in its own right, then yes it is `restful`. However, if you consider `preview` as an action, then it is not `restful`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not hard and fast rules for defining Restful web services, though Rails gives you a method called `resources` to generate Restful web services. But that depends upon the scenario.

You may take a look at [A Beginner’s Guide to HTTP and REST](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340). It in-depth describes how a request falls into a category of being a Restful request.

Answer (score 0):

In many applications, you’ll also see non-RESTful routing, which explicitly connects the parts of a URL to a particular action. For example,

```
map.connect 'parts/:number', :controller => 'inventory', :action => 'show'
```

On the other had, when you use `resources` or `resource` while specifying routes in your application's `route.rb`, you will get RESTful URLs for them such as:

```
map.resources :photos
```

will produce:

```
Verb     URL          controller    action  used for
GET      /photos        Photos      index   display a list of all photos
GET      /photos/new    Photos      new     return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST     /photos        Photos      create  create a new photo
GET      /photos/1      Photos      show    display a specific photo
GET      /photos/1/edit Photos      edit    return an HTML form for editing a photo
PUT      /photos/1      Photos      update  update a specific photo
DELETE   /photos/1      Photos      destroy delete a specific photo
```

Source: [Ruby on rails - Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html)